# Should I use index in this scenario?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, indexing

I am new to database and am struggling with a problem. I use SQL Server 2005.

I have a table (Audit table) which gets its data from a trigger on another table (main table). The Audit table can not have a PK on it as there could be duplicates. It has around 15 million rows. I am  running an update query on it which is resulting in table scans.

I want to know if I add a non clustered index, how I can test its impact on the inserts/deletes. Adter adding the index, would there be a scenario where the data coming from the trigger will be lost because the server is too busy rebuilding the table/index?

Thanks
Vikram

Comment: First of all: is there a primary/clustering key on that Audit table?? If not: **add one!** (Quote: *if it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table!*). You can **always** add a primary key - even if you need to add an `INT IDENTITY` for that purpose - better than not having one!!

Comment: Secondly: how much of the data (how many rows) does the UPDATE statement affect? Just a few rows? Then a non-clustered index (after adding a **primary key**!) on the WHERE clause of your UPDATE statement might help...

Comment: The update affects approx 500,000 rows of the total 15 million. Followed by the update, data which is 10 days old is also deleted from this table. How does this affect the non clustered index?

Comment: @Vikram - Put a clustered index on a identity column.  Having a heap with a non-clustered index isn't going to help that much.

Comment: With an update of about 3% of your data, having a clustered index and a suitable non-clustered index (preferably on those column(s) that you use in your UPDATE's WHERE clause) should definitely help!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Thats very helpful. @marc_s - I didnt know that I can accept an answer. Will do that from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add an `IDENTITY` column as the primary key and clustered index.  Since it's auto-incrementing, you shouldn't have many problems with index fragmentation.

As for losing data from the trigger because the server is too busy rebuilding the index - no, that should never happen.